# Laravel 4.2 WhereBetween Not Working

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, where-clause

I have a table like below structure,
[image]

The **entry_added_date** is storing date equivalent field, (2015-07-27).

Now I want to filer that entries in between two dates with this field.

I tried the below code,

```
    $start = Input::get('start');
    $end = Input::get('end');

 $arr = DB::table('otc_revenue_entries')
        ->whereBetween('entry_added_date',array($start,$end))
        ->get();
 return Response::json(['data',$arr]);
```

Where is the wrong in my code, ?

Comment: Do `->toSql()` and show which SQL is generated. Maybe this will help because I think code is correctly. Maybe you should use `int` values to use Laravel's `whereBetween()`

Comment: why you are not using `created_at` but `entry_added_date` ? are there rows with "correct" entry_added_date (not empty and matching your $start,$end) in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Below code..

```
    $startdate = new DateTime($start);
    $start_date = $startdate->format("Y-m-d");
    $enddate = new DateTime($end);
    $end_date = $enddate->format("Y-m-d");

$arr = DB::table('otc_revenue_entries')
        ->leftJoin('otc_users','otc_users.user_id','=','otc_revenue_entries.entry_added_by')
        ->leftJoin('otc_branches','otc_branches.branch_id','=','otc_revenue_entries.entry_branch')
        ->whereBetween('entry_added_date',array($start_date,$end_date))
        ->get();

return Response::json(['data',$arr]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your $start and $end are actually the same format as your entry_added_date, the comparison might be failing due to that.